# Change text color of OutlineButton when pressed

Tags: flutter, dart

I don't really seems to find a property in outline button to change text color when highlighted or pressed.

```dart
    OutlineButton(
      child: Text('Delete'),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0)),
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.redAccent),
      highlightedBorderColor: Colors.redAccent,
      highlightColor: Colors.redAccent,
      textColor: Colors.redAccent,
      onPressed: () {},
    )
```

I want this button to change text color to white when pressed

Comment: I posted the answer earlier, Misunderstood the question, But i'd edit it just to be clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your best bet is to create your own custom button from `RawMaterialButton`

```
Color buttonColor = Colors.redAccent;



RawMaterialButton(
  child: Text(
  'Delete',
  style: TextStyle(color: buttonColor),
  ),
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
    side: BorderSide(color: Colors.redAccent, width: 1)),
  fillColor: Colors.transparent,
  elevation: 0,
  highlightElevation: 0,
  splashColor: Colors.black12,
  onHighlightChanged: (hc) {
     setState(() {
         hc
         ? buttonColor = Colors.white
         : buttonColor = Colors.redAccent;
       });
     },
  highlightColor: Colors.red,
  onPressed: () {},
 )
```